# Load data in Oracle via SQLLDR

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I would like to load data in Oracle via the sqlldr, however, it is always loading the data in another format.

So does my data from my file look like:

```
2018-11-27      13      Vienna  1       66.90   1
```

This is the result after having loaded the data:

```
27-Nov-17 1443443505 ienna 909510961 0.9 3377
```

All columns except the date column are wrong

This is my table structure:

```
BOOKINGDATE DATE
CUSTOMERID NUMBER(38,0)
LOCATIONID VARCHAR(255 BYTE)
NUMBEROFPARKINGTICKET NUMBER(38,0)
CHARGETICKET NUMBER(18,2)
DURATIONINMINUTES NUMBER(38)
```

This is my table definition in my file:

```
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE ROTH.PARKSCHEIN_ROTH
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(
BOOKINGDATE DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD',
CUSTOMERID INTEGER,
LOCATIONID CHAR(255),
NUMBEROFPARKINGTICKET INTEGER,
CHARGETICKET DECIMAL EXTERNAL,
DURATIONINMINUTES INTEGER
)
```

Can someone please tell me which datatypes do I have to use?
I thought Oracle is find all the types by itself except the date?

Thank you very much in advance for you help.

Comment: Can we assume those are tab characters between the values in your sample data? They are displayed above as sequences of spaces but your specify the delimiter as a tab.

Comment: Yes, they are tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally easiest to leave it to the default and let conversion happen in the database:

```
load data
replace
into table parkschein_roth
fields terminated by '\t'
optionally enclosed by '"'
( bookingdate date 'YYYY-MM-DD'
, customerid
, locationid
, numberofparkingticket
, chargeticket
, durationinminutes )
```

The log then shows it did this:

```
Column Name                      Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
BOOKINGDATE                         FIRST     *  WHT O(") DATE YYYY-MM-DD      
CUSTOMERID                           NEXT     *  WHT O(") CHARACTER            
LOCATIONID                           NEXT     *  WHT O(") CHARACTER            
NUMBEROFPARKINGTICKET                NEXT     *  WHT O(") CHARACTER            
CHARGETICKET                         NEXT     *  WHT O(") CHARACTER            
DURATIONINMINUTES                    NEXT     *  WHT O(") CHARACTER
```

Note that specifying a numeric datatype without the `EXTERNAL` keyword instructs SQL*Loader to read the binary data in the file directly, not its character representation: for example, what's displayed as `1` in a text editor is character 49 (that is, the symbol representing the bit sequence `00110001`), and not an actual numeric 1. (I have never seen a data file formatted with binary encoded numbers but I suppose they must exist.) See [Numeric EXTERNAL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-field-list-contents.html#GUID-F47507D9-C188-41AE-B63E-6EBFF6D711B2) in the SQL*Loader Field List Reference.

Note following comments: it seems the line actually ended with `00110001` (the character `'1'`) followed by `00001101` (Windows carriage return) before the linefeed. Looking at the result you got, it must have read those two bytes and interpreted them as `0000110100110001` to get decimal `3377`.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. If I do it that way I get this error message: Record 1: Rejected - Error on table PARKSCHEIN_ROTH, column DURATIONINMINUTES.
ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: I changed the loader file, the column durationinminutes to DECIMAL(38), now nearly all columns are correct, except DURATIONINMINUTES:  load data
replace
into table parkschein_roth
fields terminated by '\t'
optionally enclosed by '"'
( bookingdate date 'YYYY-MM-DD'
, customerid
, locationid
, numberofparkingticket
, chargeticket
, durationinminutes decimal(38))
This is the result: 27-Nov-18 13 Vienna 1 66.9 -310 Why is the last column negativ?

Comment: I added a note about numeric field handling to my answer. I can't reproduce your ORA-01722, I'm afraid (Oracle 12.2 on Windows 10).

Comment: Î created my txt file in Excel, exported it to a textfile and then imported it in Oracle on RedHat. So, yes more or less there are some things in Windows, too. So, does it look like in Linux: 0000000   2   0   1   8   -   1   1   -   2   7  \t   1   3  \t   V   i
0000020   e   n   n   a  \t   1  \t   6   6   .   9   0  \t   3   0  \r
0000040  \n
0000041

Comment: Line terminators can be an issue going between Windows and Linux. Perhaps there is a stray carriage return messing up the last field in each record.

Comment: Yeah, I did a dos2unix now, and the last column value is not negativ anymore, it is positiv now instead. I think I have to see what the wrong value could cause.

Comment: I do not get it. I dismissed the DECIMAL datatype in my loader file now, and suddenly it works. I still have to find out why it is working now, maybe because of the dos2unix!!

Comment: Yes, it was the dos2unix command that was missing. Now, it is working! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Regarding `DECIMAL`, don't use it. In my answer I use the default variable-length `CHAR` and let it convert on insert. `DECIMAL` would require actual binary values in the C representation of a decimal type. I don't know what that as and as I mentioned I have never seen it used in 30 years.

Comment: You are right. In the beginning as nothing worked, I tried to specify the data type by myself, then after having seen that I had to issue the dos2unix command, the DECIMAL data type was still on its place and in the end I had to get rid of it. So, now it works.